# Open alert on Select Event of kendoContextMenu

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-contextmenu

as the title says i'm trying to open an alert on the Select Event of a kendoContextMenu, but the alert is shown only after the Select function is completed, is it possible to show an alert as soon as the user clicks on the ContextMenu option (at the start of the Select Event)?

Below the Select Event of my code:

```
select: function (e) {
alert("Test Alert"); //This one appears only after that the Select function ends, but i'd want it to appear as soon as the select function starts.

//MY CODE
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the API reference: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/contextmenu#events

The open or activate events look to be the options available to you.